# How to append list of home directory to a text file and how to move files?

Tags: linux, unix

I know a very basic of unix and I am writing a java program which I only need couple of commands to solve my problem.

I appreciate if anyone knows how I can get desired output:

1. What command I can use to append a full list of objects of my home directory to a file "report.txt". Assume I am in different directory?
2. What command I can use to move all files in my directory that begin with either a, b, or c, to a subdirectory, sorting, of my current directory?
3. If I go to /proc directory. What does this command do?

   cd 'ps | grep ps| cut -f 1'

I really appreciate if any one can help me out with these.

Answer (score 1):

1. What command I can use to append a full list of objects of my home directory to a file "report.txt". Assume I am in different directory?

   `ls -la ~ > report.txt`
2. What command I can use to move all files in my directory that begin with either a, b, or c, to a subdirectory, sorting, of my current directory?

   mv a* b* c* yourdirectory
3. If I go to /proc directory. What does this command do?

   `cd 'ps | grep ps| cut -f 1'`

   This command will give "bash: cd: ps | grep ps| cut -f 1: No such file or directory" error

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know for the second question how can I do it in one line?